# drop values on datetime difference, with revision

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame grouped by subject with multiple encounter dates per subject in the following organization:

```
row    Subject    encounter date    difference
0      1          1/1/2015          0
1      1          1/10/2015         9
2      1          1/09/2016         364
3      2          2/8/2015          0
4      2          4/20/2015         71
5      2          3/19/2016         333
6      2          3/22/2016         3
7      2          3/20/2017         363
```

Output:

```
row    Subject    encounter date    difference
0      1          1/1/2015          0
2      1          1/09/2016         374
3      2          2/8/2015          0
5      2          3/19/2016         404
7      2          3/20/2017         366
```

I would like to iterate over all rows grouped by subject, and remove rows where the time difference relative to the previous row is < 365, with active revision of the difference between rows after rows are removed. My current code will drop row 2 of the dataset, but I would like to revise such that the time difference is recalculated after rows are dropped -- in this case, when row 1 is dropped, the next encounter will be calculated against time 0 and will be > 365.

Here is my current code. Any help will be appreciated:

```
df = df.drop(df[(((df.groupby('Subject')['Encounter_Date'].diff().fillna(0)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int) > 0) & (((df.groupby('Subject')['Encounter_Date'].diff().fillna(0)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int) < 365)].index)


 def drop_rows(date, subject):
    current_subject = subject[0]
    date_diff = date - date   
    j = 1
    for i in range(1,len(date)):
        date_diff[i] = {'subj': current_subject, 'diff': date[i] - date[i-j]}
                                                         # changed to dict
        if subject[i] == current_subject:
            if date_diff[i][2] < pd.Timedelta('365 Days'):    # changed here
                date_diff.drop(i,inplace=True)
                j += 1
            else:
                j = 1
        else:
            date_diff[i][2] = pd.Timedelta('0 Days')          # changed here
            current_subject = subject[i]            
    return pd.DataFrame(data = date_diff, col = ['subj', 'diff']
```

Comment: first of all, you are doing to much in one line. Try breaking it up to more atomic operations, add some indentation and probably you find where the problem is

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I understand that the current code is literally dropping differences < 365, but I cannot figure out how to revise the differences every time a row is dropped. This is the step I need help with.

Comment: Working on it. I edited my example code with desired output to reflect how the loop should work. rows 1,4,6 were dropped and difference was re-calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit of a hack, but seems to work.  I added your code to handle grouping by subject and then changed in 3 places (noted below).

```
def drop_rows(date, subject):
    current_subject = subject[0] # changed here
    date_diff = date - date      # timedelta=0, same shape as date
    j = 1
    for i in range(1,len(date)):
        date_diff[i] = date[i] - date[i-j]
        if subject[i] == current_subject:
            if date_diff[i] < pd.Timedelta('365 Days'):
                date_diff.drop(i,inplace=True)
                j += 1
            else:
                j = 1
        else:
            date_diff[i] = pd.Timedelta('0 Days')    # changed here
            current_subject = subject[i]             # changed here
    return date_diff
```

Note, of course, that you need to have sorted by subject and date, and date is assumed to be of dtype datetime.

```
>>> drop_rows(df.date,df.Subject)

0     0 days
2   373 days
3     0 days
5   405 days
7   366 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

To get a new dataframe with only the selected rows, you could do the following:

```
df['new'] = drop_rows(df.date,df.Subject)
df = df[ df['new'].notnull() ]
```

Comment: Tried to edit this, but still having some trouble. See edited code in original post..

Comment: @AMS OK, adapted your edits, I think it will work now.  Your logic was pretty good, just had some syntax errors basically.

Comment: Thank you so much John, sincerely appreciate your help!! One more question: if I wanted to return a data frame instead of the series, so that the subject is attached to the result, how best to add this? I tried manipulating my code as above.

Comment: See my edit at the bottom which may be what you want and I think will be cleaner than altering the function itself.